# ResponsiveSlides is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I am using responsiveSlides Slider but it is not working till auto mode is true.
I have a code as follow...

Js Code :

```
<script src="Scripts/responsiveslides.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/responsiveslides.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/responsiveslides.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
            maxwidth: 800,
            speed: 500
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Here is css code :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .rslides {
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      }

    .rslides li {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      }

    .rslides li:first-child {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      }

    .rslides img {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      border: 0;
      }
</style>
```

And here is html code :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
        <li>
            <img src="Images/slide1.png" alt=""></li>
        <li>
            <img src="Images/slide2.png" alt=""></li>
        <li>
            <img src="Images/slide3.png" alt=""></li>
        <li>
            <img src="Images/slide4.png" alt=""></li>
        <li>
            <img src="Images/slide5.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I have also attached jquery.min.js version is v1.8.3:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I haven't made any change in all files of css & javascript of responsiveSlides files, they are as it is and I have attached files as above.

Comment: I would try adding this in JSFiddle so we can debug from there

Comment: Here it is : [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6Q7t/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing $ before (function ()...

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
        maxwidth: 800,
        speed: 500
    });
});
```

I got it working http://jsfiddle.net/3J8vW/2/ with your code.

Comment: Nice see the power of Fiddle :)

Comment: Sorry but still it is not working... & before this my code didn't give any error but now after applying your solution, it's giving error : "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'responsiveSlides' "